# C- How can i check who has won a NxN game OF O/X?

Tags: c, arrays

Im making a game of tic tac toe.

I have a function which looks for a winner after each  move is made...

The function is as follows **int won(char sym)**
where char sym is the players letter e.g. X or O.

My game can be played on any size board 3-8 e.g. (3z3 - 8x8)
and is based on a 2d array named **S[][]**
The size is also chosen by the user and is stored in a veriable **int Scale**.**(global veriable)**

**How would I check if a player has won?**(if a row, column or diagonal are all the same letter)
Im only stunning as i don't know how to make it work for any size table.

Please help!!!!!!

Comment: For starters, you can try looking in every row, column, and diagonal. Every time, you try to find a consecutive sequence of `X`s or `O`s that is long enough in that row, column, or diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines. This lines are array's size independent.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do it in `O(n)` where `n` is the number of squares, instead of `O(1)`, like the traditional 3x3, and without any modification to your structure by just by checking each square. You only need to check in one direction because it's commutative. Something like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Tic {
    unsigned size;
    char board[65];
};

static const char is_valid[] = "XO ";

/** This is a strict parser.
 @param tic Overwriten with stdin on success. On failure, is corrupted.
 @return Success.
 @throws EDOM if the file is not correct, fgets, getc. */
static int load(struct Tic *const tic) {
    char s[10];
    size_t s_len, row = 0;
    int is_size = 0;
    assert(tic);
    errno = 0;
    tic->board[0] = '\0';
    do {
        if(!fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) return errno ? 0 : (errno = EDOM, 0);
        if(s_len = strcspn(s, "\n\r\f"), s_len != strspn(s, is_valid))
            return errno = EDOM, 0;
        if(is_size) {
            if(s_len != (size_t)tic->size) return errno = EDOM, 0;
        } else {
            if(s_len < 3 || s_len > 8) return errno = EDOM, 0;
            tic->size = (unsigned)s_len;
            is_size = 1;
        }
        s[s_len] = '\0';
        strcat(tic->board, s);
    } while(++row < tic->size);
    /* Enforce EOF. */
    if(getc(stdin) != EOF) return errno = EDOM, 0; else if(errno) return 0;
    return 1;
}

/** Doesn't do bounds checks; should be inlined. */
static int is_owned(const struct Tic *const tic,
    const size_t x, const size_t y, const char sym) {
    return tic->board[y * tic->size + x] == sym;
}

/** @param tic A valid tic-tac-toe.
 @param sym Either X or O.
 @return Whether sym has won the game. */
static int won(const struct Tic *const tic, const char sym) {
    const size_t size = tic->size;
    size_t x, y;
    int is_x, is_y;
    assert(tic && (sym == 'X' || sym == 'O'));
    for(y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            if(!is_owned(tic, x, y, sym)) continue;
            is_x = x < size - 2 ? 1 : 0;
            is_y = y < size - 2 ? 1 : 0;
            /* There are 3 cases. */
            if(is_x && is_owned(tic, y, x + 1, sym)
                && is_owned(tic, y, x + 2, sym)) return 1;
            if(is_y && is_owned(tic, y + 1, x, sym)
                && is_owned(tic, y + 2, x, sym)) return 1;
            if(is_x && is_y && is_owned(tic, y + 1, x + 1, sym)
               && is_owned(tic, y + 2, x + 2, sym)) return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    struct Tic tic;
    if(!load(&tic)) return perror("stdin"), EXIT_FAILURE;
    printf("Xs won? %s.\n", won(&tic, 'X') ? "yes" : "no");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I think that is valid, but more testing is probably needed.

*This is assuming the criteria are having 3 entries in a straight line. `won` would need to be edited to change it `3 -> n`, for example,

```
static int won_row(const struct Tic *const tic, const size_t y,
    const char sym) {
    const size_t size = tic->size;
    size_t x;
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) if(!is_owned(tic, x, y, sym)) return 0;
    return 1;
}

static int won_col(const struct Tic *const tic, const size_t x,
    const char sym) {
    const size_t size = tic->size;
    size_t y;
    for(y = 0; y < size; y++) if(!is_owned(tic, x, y, sym)) return 0;
    return 1;
}

static int won_diag(const struct Tic *const tic, const char sym) {
    const size_t size = tic->size;
    size_t x;
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) if(!is_owned(tic, x, x, sym)) return 0;
    return 1;
}

static int won_anti_diag(const struct Tic *const tic, const char sym) {
    const size_t size = tic->size;
    size_t x;
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) if(!is_owned(tic, x, size - x - 1, sym)) return 0;
    return 1;
}

/** @param tic A valid tic-tac-toe.
 @param sym Either X or O.
 @return Whether sym has won the game. */
static int won(const struct Tic *const tic, const char sym) {
    const size_t size = tic->size;
    size_t x, y;
    assert(tic && (sym == 'X' || sym == 'O'));
    /* These do a short-circuit evaluation. */
    for(y = 0; y < size; y++) if(won_row(tic, y, sym)) return 1;
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) if(won_col(tic, x, sym)) return 1;
    return won_diag(tic, sym) || won_anti_diag(tic, sym);
}
```